# Convert string to numeric in R

Tags: r, string, numeric

This seems likely to have a simple solution but I am having a hard time getting it. How do I convert this string to numeric?

```
> a <- "1:10"
```

Desired solution should be

```
> 1:10
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I have tried as.numeric() (doesn't work), strsplit ":" and getting the end points 1 and 10 (can work but seems clumsy) but is there some simpler way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use eval() and parse()

```
eval(parse(text ="1:10"))
```